# REQUEST: Migrate LaTeX questions to tex.stackexchange

Tags: support, migration, latex

I found some LaTeX questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). There is [a Stack Exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com) completely dedicated to TeX and LaTeX.

I would like to migrate the questions, but I don't have the reputation points to do this:

> Flag → Closing → Off-Topic → Migration

These are the questions:

- *[LaTeX: Prevent line break in a span of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012799/latex-prevent-line-break-in-a-span-of-text)*
- *[How do I use '_' and other characters on LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180054/how-to-use-and-other-characters-on-latex)*
- *[Referring to a table in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353120/referring-to-a-table-in-latex)*
- *[Breaking a LaTeX environment across pages - the smart way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829024/breaking-an-environment-across-pages-the-smart-way)*
- *[Inserting code in this LaTeX document with indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175105/writing-code-in-latex-document)*
- *[How do I add comments on an algorithm environment in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771732/how-to-add-comments-on-algorithm-enviroment-latex)*
- *[Latex: verbatim content on one page](https://superuser.com/questions/165836/latex-verbatim-content-on-one-page)*
- *[How can I link to a local file in a LaTeX document typeset with PDFlatex on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/247967/how-can-i-link-to-a-local-file-in-a-latex-document-typeset-with-pdflatex-on-mac)*
- *[How do I cite software in LaTeX?](https://superuser.com/questions/8743/how-to-cite-software-in-latex)*

Comment: Are all of those questions off-topic where they were asked?  We don't migrate questions that are on-topic on site A just because site B specializes in that topic.

Comment: Since both the 60 days part I mentioned, and a flowchart with the "Is question necessarily off-topic on origin site" question are provided in the FAQ, I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

That won't work; questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, not even by ♦ moderators.

Also, a question being 'more on-topic' on site Y is not a good reason to migrate it from site X, if it's on-topic there as well. There's a good reason the 'Migration' option is a sub-option of the **off-topic** close reason.